# Making a simple sequencer using WAAClock and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a sequencer using the WAAClock module and using React. I've been taking the code from a slide show presentation [here](https://www.slideshare.net/VincentRiemer/sequencing-audio-using-react-and-the-web-audio-api) and a Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqGpdv?editors=0011)

Here's my current code I made in a component. It is basically taken from the slideshow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import waaclock from 'waaclock'

class Player extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      steps: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      currentStep: 0,
      playing: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.context = new AudioContext();
    this.clock = new waaclock(this.context);
  }

  handleTick({ deadline }) {
    const { currentStep, steps } = this.state;

    if (steps[currentStep % steps.length]) {
      console.log("tick")
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ currentStep: currentStep + 1 });
    }, deadline - this.context.currentTime);
  }

  handlePlayPress() {)

    if (!this.state.playing) {
      this.setState({
        currentStep: 0,
        playing: true
      }, () => {
        this.clock.start();
        this.tickEvent = this.clock.callbackAtTime(
          this.handleTick.bind(this),
          this.context.currentTime
        ).repeat(0.47);
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(
        { playing: false },
        () => {
          this.clock.stop();
          this.tickEvent = null;
        }
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { currentStep, playing, steps } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {`Current Step: ${currentStep % steps.length}`}
        <button onClick={() => this.handlePlayPress()}>{playing ? 'Stop' : 'Play'}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Player;
```

Once I press play, the currentstep will default to -1. I'm expecting it to tick through as a timer. 1, 2, 3, 4. Im having trouble with this. The logic makes sense to me from Vincent Riemers demonstration, but I've hit a wall and am unsure whats going wrong.

Trying to get something like this to work would also be of benefit but it doesnt seem to work for me:

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I'm going to post a git repo of my own test as soon as I get home.

Comment: `this.setState({
        currentStep: -1,
        playing: true
  }`. You are setting currentStep to `-1` I think it should start with 0;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ive changed it to 0 but it still hasnt decided to tick through each beat. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the way I've imported the library. I console logged the function this.clock.start() and it returned to the console undefined. But i supposed that would be a normal occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't keep it simple and efficient?

```js
let songiter = 0
setInterval(function(){
  songiter++
  if (songiter === 4){
     synth(2,590,50)
  }
  if (songiter === 8){
    synth(2,122,100)
  }
  if (songiter === 16){
    synth(2,432,100)
  }
  if (songiter === 32){
    synth(2,75,100)
    songiter = 0
  }
}, tempo.value)
 

// Audio synth: gain, frequency, duration
  audio = new AudioContext()
  function synth(w,x,y){
    console.log(w+x+y)
    v=audio.createOscillator()
    u=audio.createGain()
    v.connect(u)
    v.frequency.value=x
    v.type="square"
    u.connect(audio.destination)
    u.gain.value=w*0.01
    v.start(audio.currentTime)
    v.stop(audio.currentTime+y*0.001)
  }
```

```html
<input value="140" id="tempo">
```

Comment: Interesting. I've played with setInterval before, but wanted to try using the WAAClock. I may create a second version that uses setInterval. Thanks for the suggestion.